# Take Coordinates from json and search on Google map (Android)

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am developing a map application on Android which is about finding best roads.
The problem is not all roads name are on Google API so i have it on one JSon file.
Which is the best way to get coordinates from JSon file and show it to Android App
with lines from position A to B.

```
    {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
         "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features": [
      {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {
            "Name": "po",
            "description": "",
            "timestamp": null,
            "begin": null,
            "end": null,
            "altitudeMode": null,
            "tessellate": -1,
            "extrude": 0,
            "visibility": -1,
            "drawOrder": null,
            "icon": null,
            "description_1": null,
            "Number": "10",
            "RoadNameCo": "03_10234",
            "RoadNameAL": "MEHDI HOXHA"
         },
         "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               20.853835,
               42.601668,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {
            "Name": "po",
            "description": "",
            "timestamp": null,
            "begin": null,
            "end": null,
            "altitudeMode": null,
            "tessellate": -1,
            "extrude": 0,
            "visibility": -1,
            "drawOrder": null,
            "icon": null,
            "description_1": null,
            "Number": "16",
            "RoadNameCo": "03_10234",
            "RoadNameAL": "MEHDI HOXHA"
         },
         "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               20.854006,
               42.60127,
               0
            ]
         }
      }

   ]
}
```

Comment: what exactly is a problem? you can't parse JSON, or you can't do route on the map? That are 2 different questions, each of which was answered here already for few hundred times.

Comment: No idea how to parse json to google map?

Comment: you can't parse JSON to google map. As I said, that are 2 different questions. First parse JSON to coordinates, then set coordinates to google map. So what of 2 **different and completely unrelated** tasks is your question?

Comment: Alright thanks or your help.
How do l parse JSON to coordinates?

Comment: `each of which was answered here already for few hundred times` - search for `Android parse json`, you will find 100+ answers

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, but [check this out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCZPUeY94MU) Its a tutorial to find road and add polylines on road. I tried and I can assure you it is working. If you want to know how it works (demo), check out [this part of video](https://youtu.be/CCZPUeY94MU?t=1447). It have English subtitles

Comment: @AswinPAshok thanks for help, the polyines part is OK but the coordinates lat long taking from json dont know?

Comment: So you just want the `"coordinates": [20.854006,42.60127,0]` out of that object? and store that in an array?

Comment: Yes only coordinates

Comment: do you want that 0 in array? I can write a function which return a list of LatLng objects from the string given without 0.

Comment: That will be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private List<LatLng> getLocationList(String JSON_String)
{
   List<LatLng> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JSON_String);
        JSONArray mArray = object.getJSONArray("features");

        for(int i=0;i<mArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject obj=mArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject geometryObject=obj.getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONArray locationJSON_Array=geometryObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");

            LatLng location=new LatLng(locationJSON_Array.getDouble(0),locationJSON_Array.getDouble(1));
            locationList.add(location);
        }

    }catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //handle Exception
    } 
    return locationList;
}
```

Use it like this

```
List<LatLng> LocationList =getLocationList(Your_JSON_String);//The String posted in question
LatLng firstLocation=locationList.get(0);
LatLng secondLocation=locationList.get(1);
```

Let me Know if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just try to parse like this:

```
JSONArray lat_long_jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");
if (lat_long_jsonArray.length() != 0)
{

  String Longitude(lat_long_jsonArray.get(0).toString());

  String Latitude(lat_long_jsonArray.get(1).toString());
}
```

Comment: please check your code, it won't compile

Comment: @VladMatvienko I have given you only how to get co-ordinates form coordinates JsonArray now you have to parse.

Comment: That was not me who asked the questions, but your code is invalid. Please double check Lat and Long declaration, or usage, or whatever it should be, it is not clear.

Comment: @MuharremSmakiqi, excuse me, I don't think I want one.